# Cannot extend root partition

Tags: partitioning

[image: partitions]

I tried all other answers but couldn't solve the problem. `sda9` is my root partition. I want to extend it by using unallocated space of 145 GB.

I have booted from live USB and all the partitions are unmounted.

Comment: The unallocated space needs to be adjacent to sda9 so you have to move a ton of stuff. Move -> apply changes  -> move -> apply changes one partition at a time

Comment: Actually, i am a new user of ubuntu! so, can you explain how can i do that! i can't see "Move" option anywhere

Comment: With gparted from a live cd. https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to move partitions around, so that your unallocated space is adjacent to the partition you want to merge it with.

After booting from a Live CD/USB, use `gparted` to:

Move that little green partition to the left of the Unallocated space.

Now that `/dev/sda9` is right next to the Unallocated space, you can merge the two.

Be sure to run `resize2fs` (`man resize2fs`) to let the filesystem know about the extra space.

Comment: if i try to move little green part (sda1) to left of the unallocated part, i am getting an warning: `You have queued an operation to move the start sector of partition /dev/sda1.  Failure to boot is most likely to occur if you move the GNU/Linux partition containing /boot, or if you move the Windows system partition C:.`

Comment: Be sure to have good backups of all partitions.And you probably have to run chkdsk from Windows on the FAT32 partition or dosfsck from Linux on it as moving may cause issues. Do you have to move partitions or just create a new data partition in the 145GB space and use that? I only use 25GB  for / (root) but have very large /mnt/data partition. Newer user may find making separate /home easier. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving